# Jquery compare every three div in the same class

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller

I have a list of divs in the same class. I want to compare every three of them and set the height to the highest one. For example:

```
<ul>
<li class="items">box1</li>
<li class="items">box2</li>
<li class="items">box3</li>

<li class="items">box4</li>
<li class="items">box5</li>
<li class="items">box6</li>

<li class="items">box7</li>
<li class="items">box8</li>
<li class="items">...</li>
</ul>
```

What I've found out so far is be able to find the highest height among all the lists, and set every list to that height using jquery.

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

        window.onload=(function () {
        equalHeight($('.items'));
});
```

Is there a way to compare for every 3 div in the list and set height only to the highest among those three.

Thanks for everyone's reply. Sorry if I make you confused.I post an image below is better for everyone to understanding.

http://i62.tinypic.com/2e0vayf.jpg

On a webpage, box1,2,3 are on the same line and I want to compare which box has the highest height and set the other two to be the same height. Then box4,5,6 are on a new line, compare those three and set each one to the highest. So first line and second line will have different height, but they are all in the same class. How can I set each line to be different height due to the highest box in that line in this case.

Comment: Why are you using scripting for this, sounds like a CSS problem? What's your final goal?

Comment: what determines the height of the tallest div?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each 3rd div and find next 2 others :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("ul li:nth-child(3n+1)").each(function(){
        var first = $(this);
        var second = first.next();
        var third = second.next();
    });
});
```

So using `nth-child` you get each 3rd div and 2 other followers and you can compare this way through each other.

Answer (score 0):

nth-child works. But it is not modular. If you want groups to be bigger than three you need to add 2 steps. here is an alternative code that will allow you to change 1 number and change the grouping size.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/erjqr9j4/)

```
/*Sets up our counting variables*/
var count = 0;
var height = 0;
var groups = 0;
var tallest = 0;
var number_of_items_in_group = 3;
/*grabs the index length of list items*/
var indexL = $('li').length;
/*Every li item is looped through*/
$('li').each(function (index, element) {
    count++;
    /*if the count % number_of_items_in_group returns anthing but a 0 it adds the height
    if you change 3 to 4 it will count elements in groups of 4 rather than three
    */
    if (count % number_of_items_in_group) {
        height += $(this).height();
    } else {
        /*adds the height, adds to group, sets the tallest, and appends to results*/
        groups++;
        height += $(this).height();
        count = 0;
        if (height > tallest) {
            tallest = height
        }
        $('#results').append('<p>' + height + ' Pixels: ' + groups + '</p>');
        height = 0;
    }

});
/*if the last group is less than number of items in group it will still
add the last group even though it has lower ammount of items in the group*/
if (indexL % number_of_items_in_group) {
    groups++;
    $('#results').append('<p>' + height + ' Pixels: ' + groups + '</p>');
    height = 0;
}
/*shows tallest*/
$('#results').append('<p>' + tallest + ' Pixels: Tallest</p>');
```